# Scheduled Email CiviCRM in wordPress doesn't work

Tags: email, wordpress, civicrm

I'm using CiviCRM to setup scheduled email for my system.
As you know there are 5 steps to set up new mailing.
At step 4 : Test Send email - everything is ok
But When I finished step 5 : nothing happen
even I choose Send mail immediatelly or scheduled or not.
Have a nice day
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If test emails are going out, but the actual mailing doesn't go out, there's a problem in your scheduled jobs.  Unlike test emails, quick "Send an Email" emails, and automated receipts, CiviMail queues up your emails for sending but doesn't actually pull the trigger to send them.  This is actually a feature--it allows you to decide how fast you want the emails to go out--but it does require at least some basic configuration.

The job to push the mail out the door is a "scheduled job" found in Administer - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs.  The Send Scheduled Mailings job (called Mailings Scheduler in some older versions) needs to be enabled in order for mail to go out.  The Fetch Bounces job (or Bounces Fetcher) needs to be enabled in order to handle bounced emails.

Finally, you'll need to be sure that the cron job that drives the scheduled jobs is working.  The cron job causes all "every time" jobs to run every time it runs.  Hourly jobs run if it has been an hour since the last run, and daily jobs do the same if 24 hours have passed.

Information on setting up the cron job is at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-Command-lineSyntaxforRunningJobs

(If you're in an emergency and just need to get the mailing out, click "Execute Job" next to Send Scheduled Mailings on the Scheduled Jobs page.  That'll run the job as if the cron job just ran.)

Finally, you might consider setting a batch limit on the Administer - CiviMail - Mailer Settings page.  The batch limit caps the number of messages that go out in a single cron run.  If you're on a shared host, there's probably a limit on the number of messages that can go out per hour or per day.  For example, if your host caps the messages at 200 per hour, you'll need to stay under that level or else they'll block you.  If your cron job runs ever 10 minutes, you might set the batch limit to be 30.  That means 30 messages will go out every 10 minutes, or 180 per hour, leaving you some room for receipts and other messages that need to go out.

Overwhelmed?  You might consider attending a CiviMail training: http://civi.cc/civimail

Comment: Hi Andrew Hunt, Thank for your answer. I reset cron job in CPanel . And it work.Thanks.